# Save multiple questions in one row

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to make a scheme for an database. My problem is, that I have multiple questions they belong to one exam. That means: One Exam has multiple Questions. I don't know how I can solve that. I have try to fix it with an table between "`tabQuestions`" and "`tabTest`" but I doesn't seems to be the correct approach.

I have the following tables:

```
tabTest: ID, Name, FK_Categorie, FK_Questions
tabQuestions: ID, Question, FK_Answer
tabAnswers: ID, Answer, FK_Solution
tabSolution: ID, Solution
```

Thank you very much for the help!
Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `FK_Question` field in your `tabTest`. What you need is a `FK_Test` field in your `tabQuestion` table where you store the id of the test the question belongs to.

...if I understood you right...?

And if I understood you right, then you should use the same for the rest of the schema too. This means you need a reference in your solutions table where you store the answer the solution belongs to etc.

Comment: Hehe yes this is the short way to say it... : )

Comment: Thank you! Now it works :). The solution is so easy but I have spend so much time and don't found it out... thx

Answer (score 2):

You need to create two tables for this. One for `exam (test)` and one for `questions`.

The table exam (`test`) should have:

```
test_id, test_name
```

The table `question` should have:

```
test_id (references test_id from test table),
question_id ,
question_text.
```

Now you can have a 1:n relationship where one test has many questions.

But do not, I repeat: do not, store multiple questions in one row. That violates every possible good database design. Your selects, updates and inserts will be near impossible to write.

[This website](http://www.atlasindia.com/sql.htm) seems to have very good pointers for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Little question: Why should I not store multiple questions in one row? I have plan to store the questions in an array ant save the array in answers. How would you solve that?

Comment: aha, I think I have found it out. I the table "tabAnswers" i create a  row "FK_QuestionID" and there I can connect the different answers with the question.

Comment: @Luca Imagine this scenario: You need to create a report where you show the percentage of users that answered correctly the 5th question? How would you do that? You would need to get all your answers (meaning, your array) parse it and start searching one by one trying to identify the ones that were correct. If you store every answer in a different row, you can write a one-line query to get all you need. What if a user didn't respond question 5? You will have a variable-length array or you will have to start massaging your data putting in fillers. It can be messier than that.

Comment: @Luca exactly, that's what you need to do.